Mostrar con cy.log la salida de invoke
Tengo este testCase, y no entiendo por que en el primer cy.wrap la salida es la misma que la entrada si estoy aplicando la funcion reverse.
Mientras que en el segundo wrap, efectivamente me imprime el arreglo alreves , cuando inspecciono.
Y es que trato de imprimir con el cy.log la cadena después de aplicar la función reverse.
it('Prueba de llamada a invoke 1',()=>{
     
    const reverse =(s) =>Cypress._.reverse(s);
    const double =(n) => n*n;
      
    let myArray = ['1', '2', '3'];
    cy.log(myArray); //['1', '2', '3'];

cy.wrap([reverse,double]).invoke(0,myArray).then((myOut)=>cy.log(myOut)); //Yielded ['1','2','3'] 
       cy.wrap([reverse,double]).invoke(0,myArray); //Yielded ['3','2','1']


Eso es por que estás modificando el array original en ambas ocasiones, hay un comportamiento similar en javascript nativo.
La solución es asignar el valor a otra variable, y mostrar esa variable.
Según encontré, para cypress debería ser algo como:
let myArray = ['1', '2', '3']; //Arreglo original
cy.log('Original: ' + myArray); //Log del original - ['1', '2', '3']
//Hacemos una copia y trabajamos con ella
cy.wrap([...myArray]) //Copiamos el arreglo
  .then((copiedArray) => {
    cy.wrap([reverse]) //Encadenamos el flujo
      .invoke(0, copiedArray) //Pasamos la copia
      .then((reversedArray) => cy.log('Invertido: ' + reversedArray)); //Mostramos la versión invertida
});

Por favor revisa que funcione en cypress, mira que yo solo se de javascript jaja, pero conozco el problema.

Hola  Excorpion, gracias por tu ayuda, pero he probado lo indicado y me sigue mostrando 1,2,3  //Mostramos la versión invertida

Agrega el código nuevo en tu publicación a ver como lo has hecho, y si estas mostrando las correctas o no.
